# WordPress 301 Redirect For IP Canonicalization

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I need 301 Redirect for IP Canonicalization. So When user type http://example.com/ or example.com/ or www.example.com/ in a browser it must redirect to http://www.example.com/ .

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need to redirect is the non-www. `http://` will be added by the browser.

Use this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.example.com
# Support HTTP 1.0 (no host header)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This will preserve any part of the URL after the host and redirect anything that is not `www.` including just`example.com`. For example a good policy can be to point `ww.` to the site to catch mis-spellings, amongst others. Personally I prefer to use a wildcard in DNS so `anything.example.com` gets redirected.